# changes in scope not affecting in html

Tags: angularjs

```
var product_id = $this.attr('data-id');
angular.forEach($rootScope.cartItems, function(value, key) {
if (value.iProductID == product_id && key > -1){
    $rootScope.cartItems.splice(key, 1);
    console.log($rootScope.cartItems);
}
```

Here in above code, I'm removing object element from the array but after removing element using `splice` the `console.log()` displays the correct data results. But in my HTML `$rootScope.cartItems` still displays the removed element.

Comment: Can you please add html of your view and how your `cartItems` are used in it? Are there some `ng-if` around? Why do you need to use `$rootScope` btw? Most of all due to scope's prototypal inheritance you can see some other array in your view but not the one you are changing in your `$rootScope`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$rootScope.cartItems.splice(key, 1);
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        $rootScope.cartItems = $rootScope.cartItems;
                    });
```

I found the answer. Thank you guys for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some block of code in controller refills the cart items and hence the change is not visible.

You could set up an event to listen to remove an item from the cart.

```
var product_id = $this.attr('data-id');
$rootScope.$broadcast('RemoveCartItem', product_id);
```

Listen for changed event as:

```
$rootScope.$on('RemoveCartItem', function (event, product_Id) {
    angular.forEach($rootScope.cartItems, function(value, key) {
    if (value.iProductID == product_Id && key > -1){
        $rootScope.cartItems.splice(key, 1);
        console.log($rootScope.cartItems);
    }
});
```